# java - Возможно ли обратиться к абстрактному методу абстрактного интерфейса, используя reflect?

Tags: java, android, рефлексия

**ГРАБЛИ 1**

Пытаюсь получить возвращаемое `boolean` значение от абстрактного метода `getIccLockEnabled()`. Метод находится в абстрактном интерфейсе `IccCard` пакета `com.android.internal.telephony`. Делаю так:

```
Class cls = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.IccCard");
Method method = cls.getMethod("getIccLockEnabled");
boolean value = method.invoke(cls);
Log.i("ICC_LOCK_STATUS", value ? "Заблокировано" : "Разблокировано");
```

Лог:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected receiver of type com.android.internal.telephony.IccCard, but got java.lang.Class<com.android.internal.telephony.IccCard>
```

[Исходный код IccCard](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/f39de086fddea9e9f6b8c56b04d8dd38a84237db/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/IccCard.java)

.

**ГРАБЛИ 2**

В связи с ответом и комментариями, я понял, что нужно найти класс, который будет наследоваться от `IccCard` и я нашел его - это `IccCardProxy`. Новый код:

```
Class iccCard = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.IccCard");
Class proxy = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.IccCardProxy");
Method method = iccCard.getMethod("getIccLockEnabled");
boolean value = method.invoke(proxy.newInstance());
Log.i("ICC_LOCK_STATUS", value ? "Заблокировано" : "Разблокировано");
```

Лог:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.IccCardProxy has no zero argument constructor
```

[Исходный код IccCardProxy](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/f39de086fddea9e9f6b8c56b04d8dd38a84237db/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/uicc/IccCardProxy.java)

.

**ГРАБЛИ 3**

Посмотрел как выглядит конструктор класса `IccCardProxy` - он принимает `android.content.Context`, `com.android.internal.telephony.CommandsInterface` и `int`. Новый код:

```
Class iccCard = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.IccCard");
Class proxy = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.IccCardProxy");
Class commandsBoss = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.CommandsInterface");
Method method = iccCard.getMethod("getIccLockEnabled");
Constructor ctr = proxy.getConstructor(new Class[]{android.content.Context.class, commandsBoss, int.class});
boolean value = method.invoke(ctr.newInstance(MainActivity.this, commandsBoss.newInstance(), 4));
Log.i("ICC_LOCK_STATUS", value ? "Заблокировано" : "Разблокировано");
```

Лог:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: interface com.android.internal.telephony.CommandsInterface cannot be instantiated
```

Так как, `CommandsInterface` так же, как и `IccCard`, является интерфейсом, мне нужно найти класс, который его наследует, чтобы получить его `instance`

[Исходный код CommandsInterface](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/0742246/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/CommandsInterface.java)

.

**ГРАБЛИ 4**

Класс, который наследуется от `CommandsInterface` найден. Это `RIL (Radio Interface Layer)`. Новый код

```
Class iccCard = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.IccCard");
Class proxy = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.IccCardProxy");
Class commandsBoss = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.CommandsInterface");
Class ril = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.RIL");
Method method = iccCard.getMethod("getIccLockEnabled");
Constructor ctr = proxy.getConstructor(new Class[]{android.content.Context.class, commandsBoss, int.class});
boolean value = method.invoke(ctr.newInstance(MainActivity.this, ril.newInstance(), 4));
Log.i("ICC_LOCK_STATUS", value ? "Заблокировано" : "Разблокировано");
```

Лог:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.android.internal.telephony.RIL has no zero argument constructor
```

[Исходный код RIL](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/tools_r22/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/RIL.java)

.

**ГРАБЛИ 5**

Вывел количество конструкторов в классе `RIL` - 2. 
Типы параметров первого конструктора  - `android.content.Context`, `int`, `int`. 
Второго - `android.content.Context`, `int`, `int`, `java.lang.Integer`. Решил передать параметры первому конструктору. Новый код

```
Class iccCard = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.IccCard");
Class proxy = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.IccCardProxy");
Class commandsBoss = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.CommandsInterface");
Class ril = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.RIL");
Method method = iccCard.getMethod("getIccLockEnabled");
Constructor ctr = proxy.getConstructor(new Class[]{android.content.Context.class, commandsBoss, int.class});
Constructor ril_constructor = ril.getConstructor(new Class[]{android.content.Context.class, int.class, int.class});
boolean value = method.invoke(ctr.newInstance(MainActivity.this, (ril_constructor.newInstance(MainActivity.this, 4, 6)), 4));
Log.i("ICC_LOCK_STATUS", value ? "Заблокировано" : "Разблокировано");
```

Лог:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Думаю, что нужно отправлять параметры обоим конструкторам. Как это сделать? Или ошибка в чем-то другом? Помогите, я конкретно запутался, мне нужно передать методу объект типа `CommandsInterface` и я пытаюсь отправить его `instance` из параметров конструктора `RIL`. Но не пойму, что не так, я уже почти "взломал" эту систему. Такое ощущение, будто Google оставил возможность это сделать, но поиздевался :)

.

**ГРАБЛИ 6**

В связи с обновлением ответа, я понял, что есть класс `UiccController` с методами`getInstance()` и `getUiccCard`, вроде сделал верно, но был лог

```
class ... has no zero argument constructor
```

Причем, выводя количество конструкторов я получаю 0. Новый код:

```
Class iccCard = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.IccCard");
Class uiccController = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.UiccController");
Method getInstance = uiccController.getMethod("getInstance");
Method getUiccCard = uiccController.getMethod("getUiccCard");
Constructor[] uicc_constructor = uiccController.getConstructors();
log(""+uicc_constructor.length);
```

.

**ГРАБЛИ 7**

Оказывается на тестируемой модели (для которого и делается приложение) конструктор класса `UiccController` с модификатором доступа `private`. Это значит, что нужно использовать метод `getDeclaredConstructor()`. Теперь он возвращает количество конструкторов - 1. Я выяснил типы параметров этого конструктора -
`android.content.Context`
`[Lcom.android.internal.telephony.CommandsInterface;`
С контекстом все ясно, но как быть с `CommandsInterface`?  Я пытаюсь сделать это так

```
Class iccCard = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.IccCard");
Class uiccController = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.UiccController");
Class commandsInterface = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.CommandsInterface");
Method getInstance = uiccController.getMethod("getInstance");
Method getUiccCard = uiccController.getMethod("getUiccCard");
Constructor uicc_constructor = uiccController.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[]{android.content.Context.class, commandsInterface});
```

По идее, все правильно, в тело конструктора я кладу контекст и класс `CommandsInterface`. Но, получаю такой лог:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface com.android.internal.telephony.CommandsInterface]
```

Что не так? Меня напрягает буква `L` перед вторым параметром конструктора. Дело в этом? Что за `L`?

.

**ГРАБЛИ 8**

Новый код, конечный. Почти все!

```
Class uiccController = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.UiccController");
        log("Класс найден");
        Method getInstance = uiccController.getMethod("getInstance");
        log("Метод найден");
        Object instance = getInstance.invoke(null);
        log("instance взят");
        Method getCard = instance.getClass().getMethod("getUiccCard");
        log("Метод найден");
        Object card = getCard.invoke(instance);
        log("принято");
        Method getLockEnabled = card.getClass().getMethod("getIccLockEnabled");
        log("выполняем метод");
        boolean result = (Boolean) getLockEnabled.invoke(card);
        log("принят отаювет!");
log(result?"true":"false");
```

Лог: `InvocationTargetException`. Не выполняется третья строчка

```
Object instance = getInstance.invoke(null);
```

Comment: Обновил ответ. Смотрите секцию update2

Comment: Ну, вы задаёте вопрос, а потом дополняете его новыми вопросами. Так не пойдёт. Целью вопросов на StackOverflow является не сдача вами проекта, а ответ на вопрос. Если вам в процессе реализации нужна новая информация, примите этот ответ и задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Влад совершенно верно пишет. Не нужно фундаментально менять постановку вопроса, потому что это делает уже данные ответы устаревшими и несоответствующими вопросу. Если вам дали ответ, который привёл к решению изначально сформулированной проблемы, то хорошим тоном является этот ответ принять. Если вы использовали ответ, продвинулись дальше и столкнулись с новой проблемой, которую не можете решить, обязательно сформулируйте новый вопрос. Вы можете дать ссылку на этот вопрос в качестве контекста и оставить автору ответа комментарий с просьбой посмотреть на новый вопрос.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это 7 разных вопросов, а не один.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Method method = cls.getMethod("getIccLockEnabled");    
boolean value = method.invoke(cls);
```

Этим вы вызываете у объекта `cls` метод `getIccLockEnabled`.

`cls` - это объект типа `Class<?>`, а не объект типа `IccCard`, поэтому у вас ошибка.

Вы можете из `cls` получить инстанс нужного объекта, вызвав метод [`newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--), но вы получите [`InstantiationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InstantiationException.html), т.к. нельзя получить инстанс абстракного класса или интерфейса.

**P.S.** по сабжу - можно. Вот пример.

Абстрактный класс

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass
{
    public abstract boolean someMethod();
}
```

Его реализация

```
public class MyAbstractClassImpl extends MyAbstractClass
{
    public MyAbstractClassImpl()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean someMethod()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

И тестовый класс

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Class<MyAbstractClass> aClass = MyAbstractClass.class;
        Method someMethod = aClass.getMethod("someMethod");
        MyAbstractClassImpl myAbstractClassInstance = MyAbstractClassImpl.class.newInstance();
        boolean invoke = (boolean) someMethod.invoke(myAbstractClassInstance);
        System.out.println(invoke); // в консоле выводит true
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Я тут немного почитал javadoc для вашего интерфейса `IccCard`. Там написано

> @Deprecated use UiccController.getUiccCard instead.

Есть замечательный класс [UiccController](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/e287fea/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/uicc/UiccController.java), в котором есть 2 метода : [getInstance()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/e287fea/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/uicc/UiccController.java#105) и [getUiccCard()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/e287fea/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/uicc/UiccController.java#115), который возвращает нужный интерфейс.

Следовательно, все, что надо было сделать, это было

```
com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.UiccController.getInstance().getUiccCard().getIccLockEnabled()
```

**UPDATE2**

По поводу **Грабли7**. Вам не надо забирать конструкторы у `UiccController`, вам надо просто извлечь инстанс класса методом `getInstance()`. Если хотите делать через рефлексию, то надо делать так

```
Class uiccController = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.UiccController");
Method getInstance = uiccController.getMethod("getInstance");
Object instance = getInstance.invoke(null);
Method getCard = instance.getClass().getMethod("getUiccCard");
Object card = getCard.invoke(instance);
Method getLockEnabled = card.getClass().getMethod("getIccLockEnabled");
boolean result = (Boolean) getLockEnabled.invoke(card);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46697/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-bystrov-java-----).