# java | android - Как использовать методы интерфейса `IccCard`?

Tags: java, android, рефлексия

В `Android` есть интерфейс `IccCard`. Он находится в пакете `com.android.internal.telephony`. Этот пакет не входит в `Android SDK`, и, соответственно не доступен для свободного доступа. Меня интересует его метод - `getIccLockEnabled()`, который вернет мне значение типа `boolean`. В [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576428/java-%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf?noredirect=1#comment763488_576428) прекрасном ответе я очень много узнал, но, всё равно никак не получается реализовать задуманное. Как я понял, сначала нужно использовать методы `getInstance()` и `getUiccCard()` класса `com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.UiccController`. Так как, метод `getInstance()` статичный, мне нужно передавать в `invoke` простой `null`. Но почему-то вылетает `Exception` (5-я строчка)

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Вот мой код:

```
Class uiccController = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.UiccController");
        log("Класс найден");
        Method getInstance = uiccController.getMethod("getInstance");
        log("Метод найден");
        Object instance = getInstance.invoke(null);
        log("instance взят");
        Method getCard = instance.getClass().getMethod("getUiccCard");
        log("Метод найден");
        Object card = getCard.invoke(instance);
        log("принято");
        Method getLockEnabled = card.getClass().getMethod("getIccLockEnabled");
        log("выполняем метод");
        boolean result = (Boolean) getLockEnabled.invoke(card);
        log("принят отаювет!");
log(result?"true":"false");
```

**UPD**

Фантастика!!! Я нашел [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211420/detect-changes-of-lock-sim-card-in-settings-security-set-up-sim-card-lock/12748638#12748638%0A) на enSO!!! В коде есть первая строчка, но я не пойму, что такое `phoneUtil`

Comment: А что пишет в сообщение об ошибке? Там должно быть сообщение и причина ( caused by)

Comment: понимаете, в том то и дело, что это все) Я сам в шоке

Comment: поставьте try...catch, и сделайте printStackTrace() ошибки

Comment: он и так в try/catch

Comment: обновил вопрос, посмотрите код в вопросе на enSO